# Como posso criar um arquivo de rede neural .config a partir de arquivos .json, .h5 ou .pb?

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow, keras

Boa tarde, estou em um projeto de rede neural convolucional e gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a como posso criar um tipo de arquivo para a rede neural que chama .config

Não tenho encontrado muito resultado a como fazer isso na internet.

Caso alguém tenha um link de documentação ou um tutorial que ensine a fazer isso, agradeço imensamente.

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Um arquivo de configuração é, geralmente, um arquivo do tipo texto (não importa a terminação), voce pode criar qq arquivo do tipo texto em python, veja [esse tópico na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), mas para configurações eu sempre prefiro usar o YAML, em python tem [esse excelente pacote](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/)

Comment: daria como fazer uma extensão igual ao desse exemplo que encontrei no github ? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_ava_v2.1.config @Sidon

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com 'extensao'? o que vc ja tentou fazer? qual é o seu contexto? Qual FW de rede neural vc esta usando? veja que no exemplo que vc apresenta no github o cara esta usando os modulos do próprio Tensorflwow pra ler e gravar os arquivos de configuração, se vc tiver usando o TF, sugiro que o estude [esse tópico](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io) da documentação. Analise tambem [esse arquivo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py) do repositorio do qual vc apresentou o exemplo.